# Confusing outputs of threading

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

This code , is giving me three different outputs  , on different platforms

ON online ide the output is this
https://www.online-python.com/AZ2Ggs35KU

On my local machine on IDLE the output is this

hey3

> > > run

But according to the concept i had studied the output should be

hey
2
run

```
import threading
import time 

def demo_func():
    print("hey")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("run")
    
t1 = threading.Thread(target = demo_func)
t1.start()
print(threading.activeCount())
```

Comment: Why should the output be what you expect? I would expect some number then "hey" then "run" after 1 second, threads take time to start so I wouldn't expect it to output straight away. As for the number of threads, depending on how the script is being run all kinds of threads could have been started

Comment: well i expect the script to start from begining , coming to the line where t1.start() , happens
Then going to demo_func() , printing hey  , then sleep
while t1 , is sleeping , the main program thread goes to execute print statement at end , giving result as 2 , and then it resumes the execution of t1 , it should print run

Comment: `Thread.start()` does not cause the the thread to start executing immediately, it is just scheduled for execution. The main thread will most likely continue being executed before the thread starts which is why the thread count comes first

Comment: ok , so Thread.start() , schedules it for execution .But the behaviour is random , sometimes hey2  then run is coming , sometimes 2 then hey then run.  I want to know , can you explain all these confusing things , why is this happening?

Comment: start()
Start the thread’s activity.

It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

This method will raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the same thread object.

Comment: This is what the documentation says , i know , you are telling the right thing , but being a new to concept , i am confused very much

Comment: The scheduler decides which threads are run and when, there are a lot factors that go into this decision and each OS is different. The only thing you can rely on is that you can't say for certain the order that threads will execute

Comment: ok , but on idle why 3 is coming as output , and why hey2 , are coming on same line ,  they should be on separate lines

Comment: IDLE probably runs a thread in the background. Different threads writing to the same output often has issues as they could execute at the same time inn a multi-core environment, you need to use semaphores/locks to prevent them from mixing output often